# How to store XML in JSON?

Tags: android, json, xml, string, retrofit

I have a REST call with a JSON object in its body.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "response": "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from>heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>",
}
```

I know, it is weird and bad to put a XML in a JSON, but the backend is setup and I have to deal with this.

Anyway when I add it to my JsonObject.addProperty("response", myXML);

The JSON body looks like:

```
{"id":128973892,"response":"\u003c?xml version\u003d\u00271.0\u0027 encoding\u003d\u0027UTF-8\u0027?\u003e\u003cS:Envelope xmlns:S\u003d\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"\u003e\u003cS:Body\u003e........\u003e\n"}
```

As you can see, the `<` and `>` were replaced by `\u003c` and `\u003e`

Comment: Theoretically, you don't need to care, Java will convert those back. What is the XML parser telling you?

Comment: your json parser will take care of it, as per [The specifications](http://json.org)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling `disableHtmlEscaping()` when creating `gson` instance.